# Kafka consumer with jwt to call external API

Tags: apache-kafka, jwt

I have a Kafka consumer developed using spring boot , it consumes messages from a topic. For every message I need to call an external API and get back the response.
I need to get jwt token before calling the Api.
Is it a good practice to get the jtw for each request? Or is there any better way to get the jwt token once and share it with all the requests?
I need to send like 100 requests per second to the Api . I am not really sure how to design it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should get the token before the consumer starts, otherwise, your consumer will experience lag for calling anything external more than it needs to.

If your JWT token response comes with an `expires_in` field in the response, only then should you check that timestamp and request a new one.